# Using QUdpSocket as QIODevice

Tags: c++, qt, networking, network-programming

I want to use some standard `QUdpSocket` methods to be exact `read()` and `readAll()`. So, according to the documentation of `QUdpSocket`:

> If you want to use the standard `QIODevice` functions `read()`, `readLine()`, `write()`, etc., you must first connect the socket directly to a peer by calling `connectToHost()`.

I call `connectToHost()` directly after `bind()`:

```
socket.bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 14560);
socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 14560);
```

Now it can read, but it doesn't emits `readyRead()` signal. What is the proper way to use `QIODevice` functions of `QUdpSocket`?

`DeviceReader.h:`

```
class DeviceReader : public QObject {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        DeviceReader() {}

        void setDevice(QIODevice * device) {
            _device = device;
            connect(device, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &DeviceReader::onDataReceived);
        }

        void onDataReceived() {
            qDebug() << "received: " << _device->readAll();
        }
    private:
        QIODevice * _device;
};
```

`main.cpp:`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    DeviceReader reader;
    QUdpSocket socket;

    socket.bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 14560);
    socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 14560);    
    reader.setDevice(&socket);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Qt version is 5.7.0 clang x64. OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.2.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view it is incorrect to use ***bind*** and **connectToHost** together.

***bind*** method has to be used in cases of UDP server and ***connectToHost*** method has to be used for UDP client only. So just try to omit ***connectToHost*** call and you will receive incoming datagrams on 14560 port.

bind method description in Qt docs:

> For UDP sockets, after binding, the signal QUdpSocket::readyRead() is emitted whenever a UDP datagram arrives on the specified address and port. Thus, This function is useful to write UDP servers.

Comment: Yes it works, but in this case I have to use `readDatagram()` and `writeDatagram()`,  instead of `read()` and `write()` methods. And I want to use same method `onDataReceived()` to receive from any `QIODevie` (`QTcpSocket`, `QSerialPort` etc).

Comment: So, is it possible to use `read()`, `write()` methods and `readyRead()` signal simultaneously?

Comment: Камиль, похоже что QIODevice интерфейс можно использовать только для udp-клиента :-( Какой-то epic fail у qt'шников.

Comment: Андрей, ясно, спасибо за ответ.